# turtlebot simulator

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all , i'm trying to install turtlebot simuation on my fuerte
this error occurs

[image: image description]

### [Solved]

**Edit 1 :**

now trying to install turtlebot SDK by :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after that

```
sudo apt-get install ssh ros-fuerte-turtlebot-robot
```

but that is the result

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49906/turtlebot-simulator/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-12-06**:
What Ubuntu version are you using?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-12-06**:
@grega 12.04

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-12-06**:
When I was installing turtlebot software I installed ros-fuerte-desktop-full first, then ros-fuerte-turtlebot , ros-fuerte-turtlebot-apps and then in the end ros-fuerte-turtlebot-simulator.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-12-06**:
I installed ros-fuerte-full also ,, it seemed to must change my fuerte to electric ?

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-12-06**:
I have working turtlebot simulator on fuerte. Try to install al these stacks: ros-fuerte-turtlebot, ros-fuerte-turtlebot-apps and then in the end ros-fuerte-turtlebot-simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your apt configuration seems to be messed up. Have a look at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list and make sure the entry references precise, not oneiric. Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-simulator
```

Also, please make sure you read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting. Always tag your questions appropriately.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-12-08**:
@Lorenz thanks it works now ,, but can't install turtlebot SDK ,, Question Edited

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-08**:
Not sure what you mean with 'turtlebot SDK' but if you just install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-simulator, ros-fuerte-turtlebot-apps and ros-fuerte-turtlebot-viz to install all turtlebot related packages. And I think your original question was answered. For subsequent questions, open a new question.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-12-09**:
http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/SDK%20Setup
that is Turtlebot SDK but not for Fuerte

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-09**:
You will get everything that was formerly installed with ros-...-turtlebot-desktop with installing the packages I mentioned, i.e. apps, simulator and viz. Additionally, you might need ros-fuerte-visualization.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-12-11**:
Ok,thanks Lorenz ,, I installed them and that is Ok :)